# Interpretation for Variance of Hypergeometric Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The standard formula for the Variance of the Hypergeometric Distribution is

$$ \operatorname{Var}(X) = n \frac{K}{N} \frac{N-K}{N} \frac{N-n}{N-1} $$

Where $$ X \sim \operatorname{Hypergeometric}(K, N, n)$$

Notice this has the following striking interpretation. If we consider the analogous drawing without replacement, say $$ Y \sim \operatorname{Binom}\left(n, \frac{K}{N}\right) $$ and the well known formula for its variance $$ \operatorname{Var}(Y) = n \frac{K}{N} \frac{N-K}{N} $$ then the ratio between the variance of the Hypergeometric drawing $X$ and its associated drawing with replacement $Y$ is a linear function in sample size. $$ \frac{\operatorname{Var}(X)}{\operatorname{Var}(Y)} = \frac{N-n}{N-1}$$ Furthermore, the linear function in $n$ is the unique linear function that has ratio $1$ when the sample size is $1$ (and hence the replacement has no effect--both are a Bernoulli trial), and that has the ratio is $0$ when $n=N$ (and one has drawn the whole bag, so the Variance is $0$). This makes it almost trivial to write down the formula for the Hypergeometric Variance as long as one remembers the Binomial Variance.

## The Question

Is whether or not there is a way to see this interpretation at a glance. Is there an easy proof of the formula for the Variance of the Hypergeometric Distribution that reasons that the ratio between its variance and the associated Variance with replacement should be a linear function of sample size? Or at least, is there some obvious way to see this ratio is a linear function of sample size?

Answer (score 1):

Facts:

- $\alpha=\frac{N-n}{N-1}$ is called the finite population correction factor.
- If $n=1$ (that is, the size of the drawn sample is just one) then $\alpha=1$ and we have the variance of binomial distribution. Indeed if a sample of size 1 is drawn, it doesn't matter whether it's with or without replacement. If $n=N$ then $\alpha=0$ and there is no variance at all since we get the entire population. In all other cases, $\alpha$ represents the reduction in variance caused by sampling without replacement.
- If $N\rightarrow \infty$ (that is, the population is very large) then $\alpha\approx1$. So the variance is about that of the binomial distribution. If the population is very large compared to the sample size (i.e. $N$ is much larger than $n$) then Hypergometric(K, N, n) is about Binomial(n, $\frac K N$).

Comment: This is very useful context, and I thank you for providing it.  It this does leave open the essence of the question, which is why the finite population correction factor should be linear in $n$.